# Strange MySQL difference between local and live server

Tags: mysql

Ive got tables that store geo location data as type 'Geometry' Ive done a mysql dump and loaded the same database onto my local server.

*Now when running the exact same query on both servers Im getting different results. The query converts the geo raw data to proper lat and lng results.*

On the live server I get something like : **'-33.914937875882' (perfect)**

On the local server I get something like : ***'-1.02164062238311e-49'***

*That's a totaly different number and there is a 'e-49' at the end of it?*

1. The original data is the same on both servers.
2. The local server is a mac and live is linux.
3. Both tables are utf8
4. Different versions of mysql on each server

Comment: I'd suggest that you get the version on the local machine up to the same version as the live server - it could well be a bug.

Comment: Most problably a version difference. Also might be related to storage engines use in both... unsure.

Comment: checked storage both are myIsSam

Comment: local is the later one: 5.1.49 and live 5.0.51

Answer (score 0):

Ive reported this as a bug to mysql if anyone is interested, more detail as well.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55958